# In Gorm how can I use preload and distinct together?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have following nested structs in my Go Code:

```
type Notification struct {
    SerialNumber      string   `json:"SerialNumber,omitempty"`
    Ts                time.Time `json:"Ts,omitempty"`
    Notificationkeys  []*NotificationKeys   `json:"Notificationkeys,omitempty" gorm:"foreignKey:NotificationID"` 
    ID                uint64                 `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true" json:"-"`
}

type NotificationKeys struct {
     Key            string  `json:"Key,omitempty"`
     Value          string  `json:"Value,omitempty"`
     ID             uint64  `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true" json:"-"`
}
```

I use GORM for receiving notifications with following function:

```
type repo struct {
     db *gorm.DB
}


func (r repo) GetNotifications(serialNumber string, ts time.Time) ([]*Notification, error) {
     retval := []*Notification{}
     if tx := tr.db.Model(&Notification{}).Preload(clause.Associations).Where("serial_number=? AND ts <= ?", serialNumber, ts).Order("ts desc").Limit(3).Find(&retval); tx.Error != nil {
          return retval, tx.Error
     }
     return retval, nil
}
```

Hitherto, this code is working: GORM loads my most recent three notifications with its key-value pairs into my retval array.

However, due to a bug I have notifications in my database that are dublicates and thus have idential timestamps.

Both SQL Server and GORM offers the `DISTINCT` function for this. I tried changing my function at various places for example like this:

```
func (r repo) GetNotifications(serialNumber string, ts time.Time) ([]*Notification, error) {
     retval := []*Notification{}
     if tx := tr.db.Model(&Notification{}).Preload(clause.Associations).Where("serial_number=? AND ts <= ?", serialNumber, ts).Order("ts desc").Distinct("ts").Limit(3).Find(&retval); tx.Error != nil {
          return retval, tx.Error
     }
     return retval, nil
}
```

GORM does not deliver any notifications with identical timestamp now, however my NotificationKeys are not loaded anymore, the array is empty.Are those two functions not combineable or am I missing anything else?

Comment: I've not used GORM but I do know you can enforce an unique index on the database that will do two things. 1. Get rid of the duplicates and 2. throw an error when the duplicate row is being entered which will show you where the bug is.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison Yes that was another reaction. But still the duplicates exist already and this can just be applied for future values.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 could you share the DDL script to define the tables within your database? I've got a hard time locally reproducing it. Or if you're using Gorm automigrate capability, share the GORM annotation you use. Thanks!

Comment: @ossan Thank you for your efforts!
Indeed I omitted some information e.g. ID as primary key (my notification itself contains a lot of more information which is supposed to be irrelevant for this question.) I hope automigrate is satisfied now

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 - I can see my comment looks like I meant creating an unique index would remove old duplicates. You're right - it doesn't. You'd have to remove the old duplicates first. You can find the old duplicates by using count(*) and grouping on the primary key having count(*) > 1.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve your goal with the following code. First, let me share the code, and then I'll walk you through all of the relevant sections.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/clause"
)

type Notification struct {
    ID               uint64              `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true" json:"-"`
    SerialNumber     string              `json:"CraneSerialNumber,omitempty"`
    Ts               time.Time           `json:"Ts,omitempty"`
    NotificationKeys []*NotificationKeys `json:"Notificationkeys,omitempty"`
}

type NotificationKeys struct {
    ID             uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true" json:"-"`
    Key            string `json:"Key,omitempty"`
    Value          string `json:"Value,omitempty"`
    NotificationId uint64
}

func main() {
    dsn := "host=localhost port=54322 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres sslmode=disable"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&Notification{}, &NotificationKeys{})

    // seed some dummy data
    db.Create(&Notification{ID: 1, SerialNumber: "001", Ts: time.Date(2023, 7, 1, 10, 30, 0, 0, time.UTC)})
    db.Create(&Notification{ID: 2, SerialNumber: "001", Ts: time.Date(2023, 7, 1, 10, 30, 0, 0, time.UTC)})
    db.Create(&Notification{ID: 3, SerialNumber: "003", Ts: time.Date(2023, 7, 1, 10, 35, 0, 0, time.UTC)})
    db.Create(&NotificationKeys{Key: "a", Value: "1", NotificationId: 1})
    db.Create(&NotificationKeys{Key: "b", Value: "1", NotificationId: 2})
    db.Create(&NotificationKeys{Key: "c", Value: "1", NotificationId: 3})

    // get logic
    var notifications []Notification
    err = db.Debug().
        Model(&Notification{}).
        Preload(clause.Associations).
        Where("id in (?)", db.Debug().Model(&Notification{}).Group("serial_number,ts").Select("min(id) as id").Limit(2)). // subquery
        Order("ts desc").
        Find(&notifications).Error
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, v := range notifications {
        fmt.Println(v)
        for _, vv := range v.NotificationKeys {
            fmt.Println(*vv)
        }
    }
}
```

The code is mainly divided into three sections.

#### The structs definition

I had to adjust the definition of the `NotificationKeys` struct by adding the following field:

```golang
NotificationId uint64
```

The remaining code should be okay.

#### Bootstrap logic

You can merely ignore it. I run a Postgres container via Docker. Then, I created a Gorm DB client to interact with. Plus, I added some dummy data to the DB to be able to repro the issue.

#### The get logic

I was able to solve the issue by using the following methods (only the most relevant have been mentioned):

- Preload: to load the relationship `notifications`
- Subquery: written inline but you can extrapolate it from the `Where`. This groups the record of the `notifications` table by `serial_number` and `ts` thus filtering out the duplicated records

Thanks to this query that you can split into two smaller ones, you should be able to achieve your goal.
The final code has been added just to loop through the results we got.
Let me know if everything is okay or if you need something else, thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts. While your code works in this small PoC I somehow do not manage to get it work on our real database. The notification keys are matched not correctly. However there is a lot of "rubbish" in the keys database and cant find the mistake. Getting `[50.998ms] [rows:9] SELECT * FROM "notification_keys" WHERE "notification_keys"."notification_id" IN (32631,32630,32629)
However these IDs do not match the one the notifications theirselves,
`

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 you can share your actual data (should not be sensitive, if not you can mask them) and I'll be happy to better assist you! Otherwise, we can have a chat/call and discuss it to see if we can come up with a solution. Thanks!